# Queryset with this structure in django: Post --> Album <-- Image

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have some problems to find a queryset to get the images from post of my blog.

These are my models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='album')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=' ', blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, default=1, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.title.replace(" ", "_").lower()
        if not self.pk:
            album = Album.objects.create(name='album '+self.title)
            self.album = album
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Image(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, default=1)
    header_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos", default='/image.jpg', blank=False)
```

I decided this estructure for the models because i can reuse album model to posts, products or other objects, but now i don't know how to access to images from post
How have i to do the queryset ?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: But there is no relationship here between Post and Image. An album can have many posts and many images, there is no way of determining which image relates to which post with this setup.

Comment: when i crete a post automatically create a album for this post. Then how do I have to relate the models ?

Comment: @AlbertoSanmartinMartinez So what you're saying is that `album` is effectively a `OneToOneField`? If that's the case, you should make it that way to simplify things and avoid mistakes in the future, enforcing it at the database level (well, and because it's what's conceptually correct). And then you would query with `post.album.image_set`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida when i try this: `post.album.image_set`, appears this error: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: @AlbertoSanmartinMartinez I was just describing the relations, if you want to iterate over all the objects it's `post.album.image_set.all()`.

Comment: many, many, many thanks @PauloAlmeida your code works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your app in which you kept these models be **Music**
Try typing below in your Django shell

```
>>>from music.models import Post,Image
>>>post_object = Post.objects.first() #to get the first object
>>>post_object.images.all() # to get a queryset of all images linked with the object
>>>for image in post_object.images.all():
...  print(image)
```

Comment: I can't do this only with `Post` and `Image` model, i need query through `Album` because appears `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'image'`

Comment: update your Image model and add **related_name="images"** i.e  `album = models.ForeignKey(Album, default=1)` and then try the above code